# Robot Framework: Error running test (Parsing _____.robot failed: Data source not found)

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, robotframework

I just setup Robot Framework yesterday. I went to youtube to see some videos on how to set up and I found one that was just uploaded last month.
I follow all the steps and I numbered it below.

1. Installed Python 2.27 and added it on Environmental Variables
2. Installed RobotFramework (3.0.2) using `pip install robotframework` (CMD run as Administrator)
3. Installed Selenium 2 Library using `pip install robotframework-selenium2library`
4. Downloaded the browser drivers (chromeDriver, GeckoDriver and IE Driver) and added on Environmental Variables
5. Downloaded the RobotFramework Database-Libary ZIP here -> http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/, then extracted the
   downloaded zip file
6. In CMD, I entered `python setup.py install` (SUCCESS)
7. Next, I installed the database APIs through `pip install py mssql` (SUCCESS)
8. Then, I downloaded PyCharm Community 2016.3
9. Installed IntelliBot plugin on PyCharm

I have created a project FirstProject. Under it I created a directory testsuite. In testsuite, I crearted my testcase1.robot
and copy pasted some sample robot framework test on the editor and run it using command `pybot testcase1.robot`

However, I encountered an error saying:

> [ERROR] Parsing 'testcase1.robot' failed: Data source does not exist.

Here's my code. It'll simply open Facebook through Chrome browser

---

```
*** Settings ***

Documentation  This is my first robot framework test script

Library Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***


*** Test Cases ***

open browser  http://www.facebook.com  chrome
close browser

*** Keywords ***
```

---

Regardless of my code, did I miss something on my configuration? If not, what's wrong with the code? If fixed, will that make my test run?
Any feedback is well appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place. Some are three spaces, some are two. And your `Selenium2Library` call is only one, making it invalid. Also You have no test case. As Kootstra has shown, you need a `Hello World Test Case` header before you can call any keywords within it. I advice you read the documentation before doing any more tests to make sure you understand Robot better. http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html

Answer (score 0):

From the description I can't assess if your installation is correct or not. For now I'm assuming it is, and it's just your code that causes you some issues. When using a library, it has to be initialised. For every library there is good documentation available, for Selenium2Library it can be found [here](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html)

The below example is the smallest browser example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Hello World Test Case
    open browser  http://www.facebook.com  chrome
    close browser
```

Answer (score 0):

"Data source does not exist" simply means you've given it the path to a file that doesn't exist. It has nothing to do with the installation, and nothing to do with the contents of your robot files.

You can replicate this quite easily:

```
$ robot /this/file/does/not/exist
[ ERROR ] Parsing '/this/file/does/not/exist' failed: Data source does not exist.

Try --help for usage information.
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bryan, it has something to do with your path to a file.

Make sure to go the

file name >right click > choose "Copy Relative Path" then copypaste to the terminal.

If this doesn't work, please do investigate more on your file path.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, but it worked for me as below:

I used: robot '.\ file.robot'

You can use the same relative path with ls it will run.